# Reading a specific custom file attribute

Tags: python, file, attributes

I am using OneDrive which is adding an attribute called "Attribute" to files being added to my OneDrive folder. I want to read this attribute called "Attribute" but I dont know how. The `os` module is not providing this kind of functionality.

Does anyone know a way to read this attributes status? Here is a picture showing the details tab of the file I want to read the attribute from:

[image: Picture showing attribute]

Comment: The Windows API cal for this is [`GetFileAttributes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfileattributesa), which you can call via pywin32 or (only slightly more complicated) the stdlib's `ctypes`. Either way, you get back a 32-bit integer, which you have to `^` with [a bunch of constants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FileIO/file-attribute-constants) to get the individual flags. And if you want to convert those flags to a string, you need to do that manually.

Comment: Meanwhile, _some_ of those attributes will be available (under different names) in the result if you call [`os.stat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat_result). If you can explain which flags you need, or what you're trying to do, this may be a much easier way than calling `GetFileAttributes`.

Comment: Hey guys, thank you for your answers. Sadly `os.stats` doesnt give me the information about the `Attribute` attribute as seen in the picture above. @abarnert Ok so for a zip file I will get a `32` returned by `GetFileAttributes`. But I dont understand how I should get the attribute "Attribute" out of it. How should this integer give me that information? Thanks

Comment: You take that 32 and check `32 & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE`, which gives you 32, so the Archive bit is set. Then you check `32 & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY `, which gives you 0, so the Directory bit is not set. And `32 & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN` gives you 0, so the Hidden bit is not set. And so on through all of the bits—the only one that's set here is `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE`.